# Nearly elliptic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

If you have a second order elliptic equation but the coefficients of the second order terms only form a nonnegative (instead of positive definite) matrix, then, do you know if there is any literature about this? (For example, the matrix of the second order terms can be diag{1,1,0,0} )

Comment: do you mean positive semi-definite

Answer (score 6):

They are called [degenerate elliptic equations](http://www.google.it/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=degenerate+elliptic+equation&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=rqn9T4LwDdTc4QTmhLmJBw).